# Yii2 Nested-rest rules not found

Tags: rest, yii2, routes, http-status-code-404

I seem to have a problem using `tunecino\nestedrest\UrlRule` package. I am using basic Yii2 app and I am trying to create api as a module.

My current urlManager looks like following:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'rules' => require(__DIR__ . '/routes.php'),
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
],
```

and mine routes look like following:

```
 return [
        '' => '/',
        'v1' => 'v1/',

        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => ['v1/game','v1/server']
        ]
        [
            'class' => 'tunecino\nestedrest\UrlRule',
            'resourceName' => 'game',
            'modulePrefix' => 'v1',
            'modelClass' => 'app\modules\v1\models\Game',
            'relations' => ['servers']
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'tunecino\nestedrest\UrlRule',
            'resourceName' => 'server',
            'modulePrefix' => 'v1',
            'modelClass' => 'app\modules\v1\models\Server',
            'relations' => ['game']
        ],
    ]
```

The: `$baseUrl` is always containing: `$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());`

The api is a `v1` Module under `serverlist-api/modules/v1` path. There are all the models, controllers, etc.

Nevertheless, I always seem to receive 404 on accessing website using: `http://localhost/serverlist-api/v1/servers/`

Does anybody know what might be the cause of the problem?

//edit. Figured out that the extension should work in together with basic UrlRules, nevertheless if I add them, the request still throws 404.